# quicksort algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My implementation doesn't give correct output. i implemented pseudo code present in introduction to algorithm. any help will be great. thanks.

```
def quicksort(A,p,r):
   if (p < r):
       q = partition(A,p,r)
       quicksort(A,p,q-1)
       quicksort(A,q+1,r)

def partition(A,p,r):
    i = p - 1
    pivot = A[r]
    for j in range(p, r-1):
        if A[j] <= pivot:
            i = i +1
            A[i] = A[j]
            A[j] = A[i]
    A[i+1] = A[r]
    A[r] = A[i+1]

    return i+1

A = [10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5]
quicksort(A,0, len(A)-1)
print(A)
```

Comment: what did you expect to happend? what happend instead?

Comment: the output i'm getting is [10,8,9,9,7,7]. why is it not sorting and giving the correct output.

Comment: have you tried adding some prints in your code to see where it goes and what really happends?

Comment: That range `range(p, r-1)` looks wrong.  Why is it not `range(p, r)`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a swap with `A[i] = A[j]; A[j] = A[i]`, but all that code does is make `A[i]` and `A[j]` both equal the original value of `A[j]`.  If you were using another language your swap would look more like `temp = A[i]; A[i] = A[j]; A[j] = temp`, but with Python you can do `A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]`.  You have the same problem with the lines `A[i+1] = A[r]; A[r] = A[i+1]` which need to be `A[i+1], A[r] = A[r], A[i+1]` if they're meant to be a swap.

Comment: i see your point. i think i was swapping them wrong.